# nginx rewrite rule for wildcard domain with same subdomain

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm hoping someone can help as I am utterly confused. I've spent ages looking online, but I'm lost in the syntax, and I feel like I'm trying to over-complicate things.

Anyway, what I would like to do, is have an nginx Rewrite condition that points all domains with the same `images` subdomain to a generic `images` folder with its own subfolder.

Examples:

- images.domain1.com points to /root/to/nginx/images/domain1.com/
- images.domain2.com points to /root/to/nginx/images/domain2.com/

I found an article where someone used something like `server_name="~^(?<sub>.+)\.domain\.tld$"` and pointed the root to `/root/to/nginx/domain.com/$sub` - but when I tried different combinations to re-adjust the regex to something like `server_name="~images\.(?<domain>)$"` and point to `/root/to/nginx/images/$domain`, it didn't rewrite successfully.

Many thanks to anyone who can shed some light on this.

Comment: I don't know nginx very well, but are you sure that the good syntax is not: `server_name ~ "^(?<sub>.+)\.domain\.tld$"`

Comment: Unfortunately not - appreciate the response though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server_name directive doesn't take an equals sign. Your capture group is also empty.

You should instead use `server_name ~^images\.(?<domain>.+)$;`

The path is correct (`/root/to/nginx/images/$domain`).

Comment: @XavierLucas - Cheers man, this has really helped a lot. Can't believe how daft my mistakes were. I really appreciate your help :)